# Why do some disk brake pads use split-pins or bolts to retain metallic or resin pads?

Tags: shimano, disc-brake

With Shimano disc brakes, there are two options for types of brake pads: resin or metallic. My understanding is that the metallic brakes generally have more stopping power while resin are more modulated and squeal less.

With that said, as far as I have seen, some use a split-pin to stay in place, while others use a bolt.

[image]

<sup>A split pin used on both organic-resin and sintered-metallic pads</sup>

This is strange to me: I feel less comfortable knowing my ability to stop is based on a bent split-pin rather than a screwed-in bolt! Is there some explanation for this?

My best guess is that the metallic pads create more heat, which could warp threads, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Not sure if its wording or something else, but your picture shows two split-pins, two spring-retainers,  and no bolts ?

Comment: @Criggie: wow, you are completely correct. At first glance it looked like bolt to me with the head and the bottom looked like threads. And now looking back at all of the resins, it appears my whole statement was flawed. Should I retract the question?

Comment: no there's a good question here - I've taken the liberty of editing the question to focus more on the fastener than the pad compound, because that matches how Nathan answered.  If you feel this could be better, either use "revert" in the edit history or just [edit] onward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some caliper models use the threaded style pin and some use the bent cotter pin type one. Several of the pad shapes are used in calipers of either type. Every Shimano replacement pad that is compatible with a caliper that uses the bent pin type retention pins will come with any replacement pin or pins that may be needed, plural because there are actually 3 length/profile variations of bent pin across Shimano calipers. There is no metallic versus organic distinction involved.

For the most part the calipers that have the threads are the more expensive ones, or at least that's how they've been doing it recently. To date I believe all the road calipers are threaded, but that's subject to change. On all these calipers the pin is considered part of the caliper and is re-used. If they're lost or damaged, a specific replacement has to be obtained; there is some overlap but it's not dimensioned the same across all the Shimano calipers that use threaded retention pins. If the threaded pin is lost or damaged, a bent cotter type one of appropriate length can be substituted without issue.

Neither style is subjected to braking loads in any way. The pin is a loose fit in the hole of the pads. Braking loads from the pad are entirely pushing on the lips of the caliper that the pads rest against. The pins are there solely to prevent the pads from falling out when you're not braking.

**Update**

For anyone speculating that threaded pins are all upside, here is proof to the contrary:

[image]

This pin's head stripped out and had to be carefully extracted. It was corroded and the bike had other corrosion issues. This isn't a common problem but it happened here.

Comment: Right, if the pin sustained braking loads it would snap immediately. But I'd still prefer the object preventing my brake pads from falling out when not braking was extra secure!

Comment: Minor point - the bolt/pin is to retain the pad when its not actively being compressed.  So there are no real braking forces affecting the retainer.   Also, the retainer can't be too tight because then it could interfere with actuating the brake properly.

Comment: Try pulling a bent cotter pin out of its station. Use pliers big as you can find.  One will find it quite impossible even with the additional power of a hand tool to even come close to getting a bent cotter pin out.   It must first be straightened-- and near perfectly so if the pin is the appropriate size.  The straightening process can be tricky as well since the pin will tend to spin away from the straightening force and stay bent and in place. Even a few degrees from straight, unassisted human force is still inadequate to remove it.  It is quite safe in this application.

Comment: @CliffAB For the reasons Jeff indicates there is zero cause for concern with the bent type. They're overbuilt and never fail. In fact if anything the threaded type are the more likely to fail from coming loose. Most make the contrivance of a circlip at the end to prevent this, and all require loctite. That's not the mark of a more foolproof design.

Comment: @Jeff: I guess my concern is more that every time you remove the pads, say to bleed the brakes, you need to rebend and thus compromise this pin. Furthermore it is tricky + annoying to straighten and rebend each time. As such, the bolt seems more natural to me so I was curious why they are used.

Comment: @CliffAB It's a ductile steel they used. It's not going to fail unless you try. And taking out used pads only to re-install them is the exception to the norm anyway. And if you really want, go to a bike shop and ask for another one; new ones get thrown away a lot because of how many pads come with 3 different types. There is no issue.

Comment: Split pins have been in use for a long time in mechanics and have proved to be a reliable item if some rules are obeyed. The most important being never to re-use a removed pin!

Comment: @CliffAB the pads wouldn't fall out with the wheel in there, even if the retaining pin/clip disappeared completely.

Comment: In addition, you can't strip the head of a split pin. Which I've now manged to have happen due to poorly fitting allen-keys on both front and rear pad bolts.

Comment: I trust the pins with my life, as I continue to ride my bike. I am merely curious about the design choice, as the bolt seems more natural for a variety of reasons. If one could make the argument that the pin was a **better** choice, especially in regard to durability or safety, that would explain it to me. The only such point I've seen so far is that you can't strip it out, but bolts are used everywhere else on a bike so that doesn't seem like a strong argument. If the bolts got warped due to heat that would it explain too, but I don't know if that would actually happen.

Comment: Another potential explanation is that the braking vibrations may shake the threads loose? Note that all the other surrounding bolts are a good deal more industrial. Again, I have no idea if this is possible so I'm curious if anyone knows the real reason behind the design decision.

Comment: @Cliff AB Bolts elsewhere on a bike are used for their fastening properties, while here, the threads just serve as a way to keep the unthreaded body in place. The one upside to the bolt is ease of removal and reinstallation - the split pin is better at pretty much everything else.

Comment: @MaplePanda: Can you tell me *what* the pins are better at? That is what I don't understand, other than presumably costing a little less.

Comment: Since the split rings on both my pad retaining bolts have dislodged themselves, I'd say the pins are more secure.

Comment: @CliffAB Can't vibrate out. Easier to verify if they're loose. Cotter pins are available generically, while pad retaining bolts are unique to bicycle applications. Can't strip the bolt head. etc. Either works fine though, it's mostly a theoretical comparison. I do like not having to deal with straightening pins though, especially trail/roadside.

Comment: @ChrisH I actually have had a pad fall out for lack of a retaining pin (I got interrupted while installing the pads and missed bending the pin, so my fault, not the fault of pin technology).

Comment: @RLH that's strange because in all disc brakes I've worked on the gap between the rotor and the housing is smaller than even the backing of a pad so a pad couldn't escape through it

Comment: @ChrisH I’m not sure on the specific way it fell out, but about 8 miles into the ride the brake first started biting less, which I think was the pad carrier slipping, and then the lever went slack, presumably as the missing pad fell out of the carrier.

Comment: @RLH that sounds like quite a different design to what I'm used to, with a pad that's loose in a carrier that can move, so I can't quite picture it. But your description makes sense

Comment: @ChrisH It’s a b05s-rx Shimano pad. Just took a closer look at the brake caliper; there’s nothing stopping the inner pad from dropping out if the pin goes missing and it works its way out from the carrier spring (which would otherwise provide friction against the piston).

Comment: @ChrisH I am not understanding what you mean by "the gap between the rotor and the housing is smaller than even the backing of a pad". Since you can install the pads from the bottom, that would mean the pads could fall out again on their own (since there's evidently enough space for them to enter.) Case in point: trying to diagnose squeaky brakes right now...pulled out the pin and both pads promptly fell out.

Comment: @MaplePanda on all of mine you have to take the wheels off to change the pads. A new pad with its backing only just fits through the slot in the caliper housing. I assumed that was universal, which sounds like it was an error